# Not Able to add Whitespace or Comments in soap message of WCF Client

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wcf, soap, .net-4.5.2

I have a external WCF service reference. Due to some requirement i have to either add spaces or comments After soap Body element. I have added whitespace and Comments in Final message before in BeforeSendRequest of IClientMessageInspector But When i see the message in fiddler it omits this space or comments.
I have also tried to add and Xml node and checked that element is not stripped. So looks like omitting of spaces/comments are done by .net framework.
and Idea how can i stop that space/comments omitting?

Comment: Comments are comments - not part of the message, not transmitted. They can't be parsed. They are *explicitly* not part of the message.That's not WCF, that's the SOAP standard.

Comment: I do agree with this. Due to some pathetic server implementation i needed to pass any thing any space or comments just after soap body starts.

Comment: Then you aren't calling a SOAP service at all. You could just use HttpClient to post XML. What you ask is probably possible with WCF as well, but you'll have to go far deeper. Perhaps create a [Message Formater](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlosfigueira/2011/05/02/wcf-extensibility-message-formatters/) and override [SerializeRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iclientmessageformatter.serializerequest.aspx) ?

Comment: Thanks Panagiotis. HttpClient to post XML is out of possible solution as it will require hack of a manual work. Have tried IClientMessageInspector prior so Used it to change the message but no success. Let me see if this MessageFormater or Serialize Request Related thing have any thing to add the pathetic space after just After Soap Body Starts

Comment: If you have any such practical example link then please share